# React - How to fit JSON API data into reusable <Select> component

Tags: json, reactjs, select, components

I’m a beginner with React, working on building my first real form after taking a few online classes.

I’m currently stuck trying to fit values from a JSON API data feed into a reusable Select component.  I can make it work if I hard-code my props into the Select, but then that makes it no longer reusable!

I’m sure the answer is extremely simple, but after taking numerous different attempts at various kinds of mapping, I’m just not coming up with it.

Here’s the JSON data structure –

```
{
    "fkIDTeam": 1,
    "IDProject": 5,
    "Project": "Lewis Street",
    "active": 1
}
```

From here, I have a project form, which uses a reusable Form component, which then uses a reusable Select component.

Taking it from the top, here’s my project form code –

```
    import React from "react";
    import Form from "./common/form";
    import { getProjects } from "../services/projectService";

    class FormProject extends Form {
      state = {
        data: {
        },
        projects: []
      };

      async populateProjects() {
        const { data: projects } = await getProjects();
        this.setState({ projects });
        console.log({ projects });
      }



      async componentDidMount() {
        await this.populateProjects();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Project Form</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              {this.renderSelect("IDProject", "Project", this.state.projects)}
              {this.renderButton("Save")}
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
export default FormProject;
```

Note that I’ve confirmed that I am getting the JSON data I expect, which I can see in the console after the console.log statement above.

Next, we have the reusable Form component –

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Input from "./input";
import Select from "./select";

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {}
  };


  renderButton(label) {
    return (
      <button className="btn btn-primary">
        {label}
      </button>
    );
  }

  renderInput(name, label, type = "text") {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <Input
        type={type}
        name={name}
        value={data[name]}
        label={label}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }

  renderSelect(name, label, options) {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <Select
        name={name}
        value={data[name]}
        label={label}
        options={options}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Finally, we have the reusable Select component

```
import React from "react";

const Select = ({ name, label, options, ...rest }) => {
  console.log({ options });
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <select name={name} id={name} {...rest} className="form-control">
        <option value="" />
        {options.map(option => (
          <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
            {option.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

If I change “option.id” to “option.IDProject” and “option.name” to “option.Project” as shown below, then I get the full set of available values in the drop-down.  But if I leave the reusable “generic” text in place as shown above, my select is blank and I get the usual “unique key prop” error.

```
import React from "react";

const Select = ({ name, label, options, ...rest }) => {
  console.log({ options });
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <select name={name} id={name} {...rest} className="form-control">
        <option value="" />
        {options.map(option => (
          <option key={option.IDProject} value={option.IDProject}>
            {option.Project}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

So, what am I missing here?  How do I map my JSON data in the project form component to make it work with my Form and Select reusable components?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a Generic component such as the Select one defined above you have to make sure that the formatting of your data is according to the needs of the Component. In your case, each project needs an .id and a .name according to your mapping function :

```
    {options.map(option => (
      <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
        {option.name}
      </option>
    ))}
```

So one solution could be to reformat your data when you catch them to an Object such as :

```
{
    "fkIDTeam": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Lewis Street",
    "active": 1
}
```

This can be done by using a .map function in your componentDidMount() method.

Another solution would be to pass props to your reusable component to tell it what field to look for:

```
import React from "react";

const Select = ({ name, label, options, idKey, nameKey ...rest }) => {
  console.log({ options });
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <select name={name} id={name} {...rest} className="form-control">
        <option value="" />
        {options.map(option => (
          <option key={option[idKey]} value={option[idKey]}>
            {option[nameKey]}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

and call your component like that :

```
  <Select
    name={name}
    value={data[name]}
    label={label}
    options={options}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    idKey="IDProject"
    nameKey="Project"
  />
```

Comment: Yes!  That worked perfectly! I used your second option. Thank you so much for your help, Ivo!

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you can do here.

1. Add props to your reusable Select component that will specify the mapping between the data passed to it and the options it has to show. So you can pass the select component something like this

`<Select ... options={options} mappingConfig={config} />`

```
const  config = { id: "IDProject", name: "Project" }
```

now inside Select Component you can do a

```
{options.map(option => (
      <option key={option[mappingConfig.id]} value={option[mappingConfig.id]}>
        {option[mappingConfig.name]}
      </option>
    ))}
```

2. Change the format of the data to match Select components option.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mayank!  I went with Ivo's solution (his second option) above, but it was very similar to your approach.  I tried to give you an up-vote, but I guess I'm too new here. :)  Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: No probs @JoelMorgan

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the keys in your JSON data structure. All you need is to review your JSON in order to provide the right keys, in that case `id` and `name`. Other than that, if you will handle different payloads, you can pass the keys as props to your `select` component.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Vinicius!  Your solution was definitely my "plan B" in case the changes to the components didn't work.